# How to create toast notification with diff-diff msg in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

In project set toast notification, but its show same text, how can change text of toast notification in same code for diff text?

Comment: use this https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALToastView library for toast notification

Comment: ok, i will try it.

Comment: i need swift 3 lang code, above link is for objective c.

Comment: you can use objective c file in your swift project

Comment: add some code which you're using to show toast

Comment: use https://github.com/abdullahselek/ASToast library. It is in swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this simple function to show the toast message, just pass the message string

```
extension UIApplication {
    
   public var mainKeyWindow: UIWindow? {
       if #available(iOS 13, *) {
         return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
             .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
             .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
             .flatMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }?.windows
             .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
       } else {
           return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
       }
   }
}

func displayToastMessage(_ message : String) {
        
        let toastView = UILabel()
        toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        toastView.textColor = UIColor.white
        toastView.textAlignment = .center
        toastView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        toastView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        toastView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        toastView.text = message
        toastView.numberOfLines = 0
        toastView.alpha = 0
        toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.mainKeyWindow else { 
           return
        }
        window?.addSubview(toastView)
        
        let horizontalCenterContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: window, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        
        let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 275)
        
        let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=200)-[loginView(==50)]-68-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["loginView": toastView])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            toastView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double((Int64)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                toastView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                toastView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        })
    }
```

if you want the flexibility to display messages across the top or bottom of the screen then use [SwiftMessages](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages) library

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: any solution for circle radius?

Comment: use toastView.layer.cornerRadius = 25

Comment: i need above type circle corner , above code in square corner are show.

Comment: add toastView.layer.masksToBounds = true it will show toast with round corners

Comment: I am getting this error and app is crashing.
`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional`
on this line 
`let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
        window?.addSubview(toastView)`

Comment: which minimum iOS version are you supporting... iOS 13 and above or below iOS 13?

Comment: updated the code to support SceneDelegate and older AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2):

If the need is for a simple Toast message without fancy customization of font, alignment, text color, etc. then the following would do just fine

```
let messageVC = UIAlertController(title: "Message Title", message: "Account Created successfully" , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
present(messageVC, animated: true) {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
                    messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)})}
```

`.actionSheet` presents the alert from Bottom of the screen and the Timer takes care of the display duration. Change it to `.alert` to present it in the middle of the screen. You can add this as an extension to UIViewController and then call it from anywhere. Or just write it as a function if you need to call it only from one UIViewController.